PHPMailer Intermittent SMTP Error (OVH Server)
I've been having this problem for a while now. I am intermittently getting an error when using PHPMailer to send mail from my OVH hosted email address using SMTP.
I have now setup a test file with hard-coded recipient, message, login details etc. The code is the same every time yet I have around a 75% success rate with the mail being sent on running the file. I have used this exact same function on a different host with zero issues.
This signals to me that the error is with OVH since my code is not changing yet is sometimes working and sometimes not, however, I have just contacted their support and they have found no technical issues with either my managed hosting or my email plan. I am also not being rate-limited (this error will occur within sending the first 2 or 3 emails). I tried setting up a different email address with them, same problem.
Here is the logs for when the error takes place:
2024-07-12 11:42:07 Connection: opening to ssl://ssl0.ovh.net:465, timeout=600, options=array()
2024-07-12 11:42:07 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL: Success [/home/*/*/phpmailer/SMTP.php line 388]
2024-07-12 11:42:07 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto [/home/*/*/phpmailer/SMTP.php line 388]
2024-07-12 11:42:07 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://ssl0.ovh.net:465 (Unknown error) [/home/*/*/phpmailer/SMTP.php line 388]
2024-07-12 11:42:07 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to server

And here is the test file (censored parts but everything matches I've checked 1000x times):
ini_set ('display_errors', 1); ini_set ('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting (E_ALL);
require('phpmailer/PHPMailer.php');
require('phpmailer/SMTP.php');
require('phpmailer/Exception.php');

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$message = new PHPMailer(true);
    $message->isSMTP();

$message->SMTPDebug = 4; 
$message->Host = 'ssl0.ovh.net';
$message->SMTPAuth = true;
$message->SMTPAutoTLS = true; //I have tried false, no difference
$message->Username = 'confirmation@***.com';
$message->Password = '***';
$message->From = 'confirmation@***.com';
$message->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$message->Port = 465;
$message->isHTML(true);
$message->Timeout = 600;
$message->FromName = "Booking";
$message->addAddress("**My Personal Email**");
$message->Subject = "Subject";
$message->Body = "Test message body";
$message->send();

As I said, this works 75% of the time and it has never been used to send more than, say, 100 emails per day.
I am stumped and would really appreciate any help since OVH are fairly convinced that the problem is not on their end.
Thanks in advance.

The important line in there is Failed to enable crypto error. That is most likely to be server-side issue, and you should be able to diagnose it using the openssl command-line client, as described in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide. As for it being intermittent, OVH are big enough to have a pool of mail servers and it may be an issue on only some of them, but it's random which one you get.

@Synchro Thank you for the reply. The server I am using is a managed web hosting service without root access but I will try this openssl command-line on another server I have which may also help me diagnose whether it is just that individual server...

Try to use smtp.mail.ovh.net instead of ssl0.ovh.net

Thank you for the reply, issue appears to have fixed itself once I tried connecting to a different mail server for testing purposes. It clearly reset something to do with the SSL and now it's working.
